# How to solve the below usecase using hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, sqoop

```
Migrating the data from Legacy database [~50 TB] to New Database.
Migrating data from staging database[ 5GB per 1 hr] to New Database.

Before storing into new database we are doing data analytic(validating, removing unwanted data and , storing only valid data)
```

Kindly provide the architecture using Hadoop ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can Cloudera manager and CDH (hadoop).

ETL: Sqoop 2 
SQL: Hive & Impala
Data mining: Spark.

Sqoop can easily load data from your legacy database to hadoop (simple command)

```
Sqoop import --connect [jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:port/servicename] --username xxx --password xxx --table xxx --hive-table
```

After that, you can use HUE (web interface to write SQL, metadata, workflow) to query your data.

Impala is a MPP database of Cloudera.

It is easy to scale out.

Firstly for prove of concept, you can start your cluster from 4 nodes:

Master Node (*1): 64G Memory
Slave Node(*3)  : 32G Memory

Load small amount of data into data lake.
When it is done, you can scale out and add more nodes into data lake.